# Updating Column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I created a table with the following attributes :

```
 TABLE "VENDORACCOUNT" 

 (  "VEN_ACCOUNTID" 
    "VEN_REGNO" 
    "VEN_TXDATE"
    "VEN_INVOICE_REFNO"
    "TOTALAMOUNT"
    "PAID_TOVEN"
    "BALANCE"
)
```

I take the `TOTALAMOUNT` column value through a `POPUP LOV` from another table on the basis of its `VEN_INVOICE_REFNO` value. Here the scenario is that the `TOTALAMOUNT` column value is subtracted from the `PAID_TOVEN` column value. But the next time I select the `TOTALAMOUNT` value it does not show me the updated value. It shows me the old value as shown in the report below.

Query of Report:

```
select "VEN_ACCOUNTID",
      "VEN_REGNO" ,
      "VEN_TXDATE" ,
      "VEN_INVOICE_REFNO" as ,
      "TOTALAMOUNT" as ,
      "PAID_TOVEN" as ,
       TOTALAMOUNT-PAID_TOVEN as "Balance"
 from    "VENDORACCOUNT"
```

[image: report screenshot]

In the above report I want that whenever I do the second entry it should show me the subtracted  or updated value ie `1800` instead of `2800` and `4550` instead of `9550` respectively. So the next time I can subtract the amount from `1800` and `4550`.

---

I created this trigger

```
create or replace trigger "VENDORACCOUNT_T2"
BEFORE
insert or update or delete on "VENDORACCOUNT"
for each row
begin
DECLARE new_balance INT; 
DECLARE new_total INT;
DECLARE new_paid INT;

   SELECT balance INTO old_balance,
   total INTO old_total,
       PAID_TOVEN INTO new_paid
   FROM vendoraccount
   WHERE ven_regno = new.ven_regno
   AND VEN_INVOICE_REFNO = new.VEN_INVOICE_REFNO;

   UPDATE vendoraccount SET TOTALAMOUNT = old_total + old_balance - new_paid,
   balance = TOTALAMOUNT - new_paid
   WHERE VEN_REGNO= new.VEN_REGNO
   AND VEN_INVOICE_REFNO = new.VEN_INVOICE_REFNO;

end;
```

and am getting this error:

> ERROR: PLS-00103: 'Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one
>   of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current curs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a trigger. You can create a view based on the below query and then create the RECORD GROUP for your LOV based on the `VIEW`. The query would look like-

```
select accid,regno,inv_refno,LAG(bal,1,totalamount) OVER (PARTITION BY regno ORDER BY accid) "TOTALAMOUNT", paid_toven, bal
from (with temp_data as
       (select 2 accid,3 regno, 16 inv_refno, 2800 totalamount, 1000 paid_toven from dual
         union
        select 3 accid,3 regno, 16 inv_refno, 2800 totalamount, 2000 paid_toven from dual
         union
        select 4 accid,8 regno, 22 inv_refno, 9550 totalamount, 5000 paid_toven from dual
         union
        select 5 accid,8 regno, 22 inv_refno, 9550 totalamount, 5000 paid_toven from dual
         union
        select 6 accid,8 regno, 22 inv_refno, 9550 totalamount, 8000 paid_toven from dual)
      select accid,regno,inv_refno,totalamount,paid_toven,totalamount-paid_toven bal       
      from temp_data);
```

The output is -

```
ACCID REGNO INV_REFNO TOTALAMOUNT PAID_TOVEN BAL
----- ----- --------- ----------- ---------- ---
    2     3        16        2800       1000 1800 
    3     3        16        1800       2000 800 
    4     8        22        9550       5000 4550 
    5     8        22        4550       5000 4550 
    6     8        22        4550       8000 1550
```

So based on your table the query would be-

```
select accid,regno,inv_refno,LAG(bal,1,totalamount) OVER (PARTITION BY regno ORDER BY accid) "TOTALAMOUNT", paid_toven, bal
    from (select accid,regno,inv_refno,totalamount,paid_toven,totalamount-paid_toven bal       
          from VENDORACCOUNT);
```

The query does pretty much what you want, but your sample data does not look right. This is actually one example of a running total.

Comment: Here in the above queries you are entering data by yourself ? i will be entering data in the form or let me know about that.Well i have also the trigger can you modify it for me .

Comment: So i guess you did not read the part where I mention `So based on your table the query would be...`

Comment: i read it.. i understand the query but i don't understand the second part which is in detail..should i will be using that or it is for understanding .. ?

Comment: Your Output is wrong by the way..Look at your output..If you subtract 2000 from 1800 i-e 1800-2000=-200 and your result is 800

Comment: Buddy, I am giving you an idea on how to go about solving the problem. You don't expect me to do your homework or complete your project right? Coz if you are then u are at the wrong place.

Comment: And for your convenience the second part is removed if its too confusing.